# Removing all sentences that begin with a specific word

Tags: r, regex

I have a dataset with a "Notes" column, which I'm trying to clean up with R. The notes look something like this:

- Collected for 2 man-hours total. Cloudy, imminent storms.
- Collected for 2 man-hours total. Rainy.
- Collected 30 min w/2 staff for a total of 1 man-hour of sampling. Sunny.
- ..And so on

I want to remove all sentences that start with "Collected" but not any of the sentences that follow. The number of sentences that follow vary, e.g. from 0-4 sentences afterwards. I was trying to remove all combinations of Collected + (last word of the sentence) but there's too many combinations. Removing Collected + [.] removes all the subsequent sentences. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thank you in advance.

Comment: To make it more complicated, some of my data has e.g. "Collected for 2.5 man-hours total. Cloudy, imminent storms.". So what I've been getting with @Alexey Ferapontov method is "5 man-hours total. Cloudy, imminent storms." Any suggestions there? Thanks everyone, learning a lot.

Answer (score 5):

An option using `gsub` can be as:

```
gsub("^Collected[^.]*\\. ","",df$Notes)

# [1] "Cloudy, imminent storms."
# [2] "Rainy."                  
# [3] "Sunny."
```

> ```
> Regex explanation:
>
>  - `^Collected`    : Starts with `Collected`
>  - `[^.]*`         : Followed by anything other than `.`
>  - `\\. `          : Ends with `.` and `space`.
> ```

Replace such matches with `""`.

**Data:**

```
df<-read.table(text=
"Notes
'Collected for 2 man-hours total. Cloudy, imminent storms.'
'Collected for 2 man-hours total. Rainy.'
'Collected 30 min w/2 staff for a total of 1 man-hour of sampling. Sunny.'",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: If the "Collected" starts at sentence that are not the start of the string

Comment: @akrun I interpreted as if a `Notes` multiple sentences then the first part which starts with `Collected` should be removed but other parts of that `Notes` should be kept. Not sure if OP wants in that way.

Comment: I was thinking that suppose you have a sentence like `Collected for 2 man-hours total. Cloudy, imminent storms. Collected for 2 man-hours`

Comment: @akrun That's a valid point to be considered as well. Your point is valid.

Comment: Thanks everyone! @MKR, I was trying to do what you had interpreted.

Comment: I'm not sure why but Alexey Ferapontov worked but I couldn't get @MKR to work. More about my data: I took data in from a csv, took as.character(df$Notes) to remove the levels  (class was factor). Could that be the reason? Just trying to learn text mining.

Comment: @Tammy The one possibility is that sentences are starting with `' '` (`space`) character in the beginning. If so then you can try solution as `gsub("^\\s*Collected[^.]*\\. ","",df$Notes)`

Answer (score 4):

```
a = "Collected 30 min w/2 staff for a total of 1 man-hour of sampling. Sunny."
sub("^ ","",sub("Collected.*?\\.","",a))

> [1] "Sunny."
```

Or if you know that there will be a space after the period:

```
 sub("Collected.*?\\. ","",a)
```

Comment: I understand your second line (the space after the period) but could you explain why you used sub twice in the first code?

Comment: @Tammy That line is equal to `gsub("^ |Collected.*?\\.","",a)`. It removes a single space at the beginning and any substring starting with `Collected` and up to and including the first `.` char.

Comment: @Tammy The first sub leaves a space if "Collected...." was found in the sentence. Wiktor's solution fixes that